# Radio Streaming without flash player?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application to stream live radio.Which method can I use for developing such an application .I have just tried adding html code in html file in assets folder and load  them in webview .But it doesnt work without flashplayer .I need to stream it without flash player.
I used [Radio](http://keralaradio.in/) this link as HTML code .